# Delete variables in immediate window in C#

Tags: c#

Once I've created a variable in the immediate window in C# (VS2008), is there any way to delete it so I can create a new variable with the same name but a different type? Apart from restarting the program that is.

The reason would be to keep the immediate window's namespace clean, since it's difficult to keep track of variable declarations once they scroll off the visible part of the window.

Comment: Note that if you were asking about VB.NET, the answer would've been Yes: see the $delete psuedovariable at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a dictionary to hold your immediate window "variables".  Then you can remove items from the dictionary when you're done with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to keep namespace clean, you can use object instead of the types you've declared for the variable? But, don't know if there exists any method to clear them!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to the following:

```
public void LolFunction() {
    {
        int main = 0;
        Console.Writeline(main);
    }
    {
        string main = "Roflstring";
        Console.Writeline(main);
    }
}
```